# Chapter top separation for KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script

I have made a toggle that switches behaviour for chapters in KOMA-Script to place them on the same page (kind of like sections). I would like consistent sepration between the header and chapter, but it seems to differ. I use `patchcmd` to intercept the `clearpage` part of `\scr@startchapter` and inject the toggle, and control chapter-chapter sep with a vspace. For a chapter that starts on a new page, I was under the impression that `\gdef\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{19pt}}` would do the trick, but it seems to not work at times.  I notice that the chapters where the spacing is not applied, the header is blank--I think this is this because the prior chapter is still "active".

MWE below.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[enable]{pagegrid}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=20pt]{chapter}

\def\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{ChapOnSamePage}

\gdef\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{19pt}}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{%
  \iftoggle{ChapOnSamePage}{\vspace{2em}}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}%
}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Space I want when chap starts new page}
Hi
\blindtext

\chapter{}
Hi

\toggletrue{ChapOnSamePage}

\chapter{Chaps on same page here and below}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{too close here}
\blindtext

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{too close here too}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\pagebreak

\chapter{pagebreak before me -- looks good}
Hi

\togglefalse{ChapOnSamePage}
\chapter{Chaps back on new page}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vspace is for in-between chapters and works fine. I prefer a toggle because some parts of the doc require it, some don't. The problem is the inconsistency I'm seeing.

Comment: The problem is the *inconsistent spacing*... look at the images. Chapter 1 has more space than 6 and 9, but some other chapters are fine like 1.

Comment: Can you explain why then some chapters are okay and others are not? @cabohah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section style `chapter` of KOMA-Script is designed to start on a new page. So there are not any mechanisms to prevent page breaks between `\chapterheadstartvskip` and the chapter title. So in your case, after patching the style, the automatic page break sometimes happen before the vertical distance, but sometimes it happens after it.

You could, for example, prevent this using package [`needspace`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace) to force a page break, when you are to near to the page end:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[enable]{pagegrid}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=20pt]{chapter}

\def\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{ChapOnSamePage}
\usepackage{needspace}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{%
  \iftoggle{ChapOnSamePage}{\needspace{4em}\vspace{2em}}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}%
}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Space I want when chap starts new page}
Hi
\blindtext

\chapter{}
Hi

\toggletrue{ChapOnSamePage}

\chapter{Chaps on same page here and below}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{too close here}
\blindtext

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{too close here too}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\pagebreak

\chapter{pagebreak before me -- looks good}
Hi

\togglefalse{ChapOnSamePage}
\chapter{Chaps back on new page}
Hi

\chapter{}
Hi

\end{document}
```

However, I do not like the while idea of inconsistensy in the behave of `\chapter`. Usually a chapter should be a chapter and all chapters should behave same. If some chapters should not be chapters, you should use and maybe define another section command for those, IMHO.

Note also: Because those patches are always evil, [the KOMA-Script author suggests another idea to prevent page breaks for chapters](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_ChapterNoNewPage/).

Comment: Good idea for recommending neespace... that's more or less what I need. For my needs, things like list of figures and tables may be on on the same page as well as some appendices.

Comment: Just a note: KOMA-Script provides option `listof=leveldown` for list of figures and list of tables in the same page. See the manuals for more information.